# WebSocket connection to 'ws://./' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, websocket, modernizr

I dont have any knowledge in websockets, i am using a admin template from here

```
https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template
```

i don't know did i do something wrong or how it is giving this problem but i am getting this error in the google chrome Console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://./' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

it is reffering this file `modernizr-build.min.js:2` for error.

**Note:**
Error is only Showing in Google Chrome, but in Firebug this error is not showing up?

Anyone Knows why i am getting this error and how to get rid of this error without compromising anything else in theme?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have to use the FQDN for the WS URL.
There is a good small sample code here:
[How to construct a WebSocket URI relative to the page URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406930/how-to-construct-a-websocket-uri-relative-to-the-page-uri)

Comment: Is it possible i am getting this error cuz i am using local apache and php, if i upload my website to server and server have support for websockets then i will not get this error?

Comment: Also Please Tell when do i have to define the FDQN, i mean in which file?

Comment: Just seen that it is in the modernizr script. So you actually cannot set the FQDN without editing the original file. What is your local DN? localhost? Is your hosts file ok?