# HTML 5 Web Sockets Error

Tags: java, html, sockets, websocket

I am trying to implement HTML5 web socket using Netbeans and Apache server..

the implementation is working fine in my laptop but when i am trying to access the same program on other machines connected in  LAN using IP address ...i get the error "connection closed" in other machine.

here is my index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Echo Chamber</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="messageinput"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="openSocket();" >Open</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="send();" >Send</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="closeSocket();" >Close</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <!-- Server responses get written here -->
        <div id="messages"></div>
    </center>
        <!-- Script to utilise the WebSocket -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var webSocket;
            var messages = document.getElementById("messages");


            function openSocket(){
                // Ensures only one connection is open at a time
                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                   writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }
                // Create a new instance of the websocket
                webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/HTML_5_Socket_Appache/echo");

                /**
                 * Binds functions to the listeners for the websocket.
                 */
                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    // For reasons I can't determine, onopen gets called twice
                    // and the first time event.data is undefined.
                    // Leave a comment if you know the answer.
                    if(event.data === undefined)
                        return;

                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection closed");
                };
            }

            /**
             * Sends the value of the text input to the server
             */
            function send(){
                var text = document.getElementById("messageinput").value;
                webSocket.send(text);
            }

            function closeSocket(){
                webSocket.close();
            }

            function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my java file :

> ```
> import java.io.IOException;
> import javax.websocket.OnClose;
> import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
> import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
> import javax.websocket.Session;
> import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
>  /**
>    * @ServerEndpoint gives the relative name for the end point
>    * This will be accessed via ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo
>    * Where "localhost" is the address of the host,
>    * "EchoChamber" is the name of the package
>    * and "echo" is the address to access this class from the server
>    */
> @ServerEndpoint("/echo")  public class EchoServer
> {
> /**
>  * @OnOpen allows us to intercept the creation of a new session.
>  * The session class allows us to send data to the user.
>  * In the method onOpen, we'll let the user know that the handshake was 
>  * successful.
>  */
> @OnOpen
> public void onOpen(Session session){
>     System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
>     try {
>         session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
>     } catch (IOException ex) {
>         ex.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * When a user sends a message to the server, this method will intercept the message
>  * and allow us to react to it. For now the message is read as a String.
>  */
> @OnMessage
> public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
>     System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);
>     try {
>         session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
>     } catch (IOException ex) {
>         ex.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * The user closes the connection.
>  * 
>  * Note: you can't send messages to the client from this method
>  */
> @OnClose
> public void onClose(Session session){
>     System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
> } }
> ```

please help me as to where i am getting wrong which prevents the code to run only in my machine and no other machines connected in the network.

Comment: if it is not on the same machine then why are you calling `webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/HTML_5_Socket_Appache/echo");
` from your client?

Comment: Please guide me what should i do then ?

Comment: change localhost to the host/ipaddress that the server is running on.

Comment: Regarding your onopen-called-twice problem: check the readyState of the connection. On Chrome I'm seeing CONNECTING (0) then OPEN (1).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with Origin verification - you need to set your server to actually serve the (static) html page - not just deployed websocket endpoint.After that, Origin header will be added with the same host (by browser runtime) and everything should work as expected.

You should use something similar to [[how to construct a websocket uri relate to the page uri]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406930/how-to-construct-a-websocket-uri-relative-to-the-page-uri), which would let you use relative uri for your websocket endpoint (compared to hardcoded value you have now).