# How do I format the url parameter of the TwiML <Stream> element as a relative url

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to route a connecting Twilio call to a relative URL. I have tried formatting this URL in many ways but all get an error that the URL is malformed. Twilio's [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#attributes) explicitly stated that this attribute can be relative. Below is the TwiML that I am trying.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Response>
          <Connect>
            <Stream url="./call_data">
           </Stream>
          </Connect>
        </Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you accessing that TwiML? I assume it's via HTTP and that would explain the problem. Your relative URL would then also use the HTTP protocol whereas the docs state `WSS` is required:

> [`wss` is the only supported protocol](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#attributes)

What you can do to mimic a relative URL, is to build it based on the host parameter you receive from the incoming request.

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");

  res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Start>
      <Say>I will stream the next 60 seconds of audio through your websocket</Say>
      <Pause length="60" />
    </Response>
  `);
});
```

Comment: I am responding to an HTTP request. How could I interact with the TwiML such that relative URLs are possible?

Comment: I'm not aware that this is possible. There is also a larger [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406930/how-to-construct-a-websocket-uri-relative-to-the-page-uri) around the same lines. However, I added a neat workaround to the answer above. Feel free to mark it as correct if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, a little odd that the documentation mentions it can be relative if there's no way to actually use it in such a fashion. Thanks for your help though.